# Button type="image" not working

Tags: html, image, button, input

Got an odd situation - when I change the "type" of my button from "button" to "image", it stops working. I have done this change 100 times on my site, and I've never come across this issue before.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
//working
<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="window.location='some/page.php'" />

//not working
<input type="image" src="/link/to/image.png" onClick="window.location='some/page.php'" />
```

I've tested it by using the first code and checking it transfers me to the desired page. Then I've simply changed the type over and replaced the "value" with the relevant "src". The button displays fine but when clicked, I simply land back on the page I was originally on.

What's really bugging me is that the second snippet of code is working absolutely fine across the rest of my site. It's just this page that it's not working on.

Really confused - anyone encountered this before or got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably put the image map in a form. When you click it you are submitting the form.

You should use a regular link instead. There is no need to use an image map or JavaScript here.

```
<a href="some/page.php">
    <img src="/link/to/image.png" alt="appropriate alternative text goes here">
</a>
```

Comment: can use a background image to anchor tag also..or an onClick event on <img />

Comment: The image tells the user where the link goes. It is content. A background image is inappropriate.

Comment: Images are not designed to be interactive controls, so they cannot be focused by default. An image should never be the click target for something (a link containing an image is fine, the link is the click target).

Comment: Using an image with a click event violates two (related) principles of good web design: [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: better to style buttons or link using pure css, probably gradients

Comment: I don't think you can infer that much about what the image contains based on the code provided.

Comment: For all those interested, the picture was simply a back arrow! But the hyperlink technique above worked absolutely fine - I must have suffered some brain freeze or something. Still not sure why the code worked on all the other pages - I checked that it wasnt in a form too. Ahh well. THanks all for your help as ever!

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return false` from the **event handler** to prevent the **default action** as input `type=image` acts as a **submit button**.

You can use also use simple `<img />` tag instead of `<input />`